# Troubleshooting Labels Disappearance Caused by the Endfloat Package

Tags: pdftex

The inclusion of the endfloat package in the LaTeX document often leads to issues where the labels of tables and figures fail to render correctly. This issue manifests as the absence of table and figure numbers when referencing them using the `\ref{label}` command, instead displaying "??".

```
\documentclass{ws-jtca}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[super]{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[pagewise, displaymath, mathlines]{lineno}
\linenumbers

\usepackage[nomarkers, tablesfirst]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
% \alph{counter} : a, b, c, etc.
\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig:repere}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
 \caption{Figure caption.}
 \label{fig:repere}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figure also disappear when using endfloat package.

[image]

How could I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please extend your example to a full but minimal self contained example (aka no external resources like files to be input or exaternal images, instead of images you can use `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`) that others can copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to understand what you are doing, and try to help. Additionally, since this class is not a standard class, a link to where to download it will be useful as well.

Comment: The class redefines \enddocument and so breaks the \AtEndDocument hook and this breaks endnote. This should be reported to the class maintainer.